# How to integrate Phone Pay gateway in android studio for card payment

Tags: android

Here is the documentation link Android SDK: https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/android-pg-sdk-integration . I am trying to integrate phone pay gate way for Card Payment.I have witten the code with passing my own details but it is not working. I am passing  request to the upi app . It is working fine for UPI apps in phone pay but not working for card payment. May I  need to the request someware else not getting exact solution. When i tried to above request with api app getting  this response In  onActivityResult.E/onActivityResult4: key_error_code : ERROR_B2B_API_RETURNED_ERROR
What should be the next or solution to this .

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: did you get the solution? if yes please share